# Is it possible to do Session hijacking through ssh proxy or vpn tunnel?

Tags: security

I used ssh proxy to visit my gmail some days ago.

Firefox uses autoproxy that setting the proxy server 127.0.0.1 (port is the same as tunneling setting) and select socks5, then I run tunneling and connect ssh server.

When I open two tabs at the same time in firefox, one is gmail (https) and the other is the page on ssh server (to get the session).

Now my question: “Is it possible to do Session hijacking on the ssh server? (if I have access as "root" on the ssh server?

```
[me]<->[ssh server]<---->[proxy]<-->[website]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clear method on my mind to make a session hijacking on your ssh server, but, for sure that if someone got the root access to your tunnel box, it could be easy to install a modified ssh server to make this kind of attack, or facilitate the access to the information that you are downloading/uploading.

Using a https site over a ssh tunnel will make things a little difficult to the attacker, but remember, from your tunnel to the internet, the information may not be encrypted.